# Graph that can be drawn to scale

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, triangles, planar-graphs

What do you call a weighted graph that you can draw to scale so that every edge is the length of its weight?
I understand in just 2 dimensions one of the conditions is that the graph is planar but I figured this is not enough since every "triangle" must meet the triangle inequalities.

Comment: Why should it be planar? Imagine a graph representing a road map, where the length of the road is its weight. Now consider bridges.

Comment: You are definitely right about the triangle inequality piece though. I am not sure if there is a name for such a graph.

Comment: @gt6989b If the edges are allowed to be curved, then it is not the case that the triangle must meet the triangle inequality. Two legs can then be straight lines and the third line can be as wiggly as you like and hence be arbitrarily longer than the sum of the other two lines.

Comment: If the drawing need not be planar (but we still draw edges with straight lines) this is the question of whether the graph, considered as a finite metric space, can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$ isometrically. I suggest you look into the field of *metric embeddings*.